# How to show all recent modified documents by search?

Tags: search, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises. I am using a Search result webpart. Which query do I need to use, to show "my recent documents" ? Also the documents in this scenario:

I modify some document. After me another colleague modified also this document. I still would like to show this document in the search result webpart "My recent documents". How can I do this?